# How to make an action only when my Frame disappear on the screen in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, awtrobot

I need to take a screenshot of an area of my screen, to make that i use "Robot" in Java. But if the user place the windows in the area, the windows will be on the screenshot instead of the background.

I tried to solve my problem by placing a :

```
myframe.setVisible(false);
```

But when i look the screenshot the windows appear on it. I thought it was because the windows didn't have enough time to disappear or because the render of the screen wasn't updated yet, so i tried different things like using:

```
repaint();
```

Or by placing a

```
try{}finally{}
```

block to be sure that the actions in the try block have been finished.
But no one of these solution works. These is other ways in my mind but they looks globally bad because they use functions to wait.

So is there a good solution to my problem?

Comment: To get a better and sooner help provide a [MCVE]

Comment: are you trying to make a screen capture in java?

Comment: No, i just want to take the screenshot only when the frame has disappeared, when i'm trying to make invisible the frame and then taking my screenshot my frame appear on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window listener to fire the screen shot when window is closing:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

    public MainFrame() {

        super("Test Frame");
        JLabel displayMsg = new JLabel("    Close window");
        getContentPane().add(displayMsg);

        addWindowListener(this);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

        System.out.println("WindowListener method called: windowClosing.");
        //add you screen capture code here
    }

  //--Not used

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
       //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
         //do nothing
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to take the actual screenshot. Not 100% sure, but I think that `myframe.setVisible(false);` doesn't become effective till the program flow goes back to the event dispatching loop.

EDIT: 
instead of

```
  useRobotToMakeScreenshot();
```

write

```
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          useRobotToMakeScreenshot();
      }
  }
```

(of course, you have to replace `useRobotToMakeScreenshot()` with the actual call to the method that does the screenshooting thing)

Comment: Can you be more precise please, I didn't understood very much your answer and it seems that it's what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Firetiger72 look at my expanded answer, hope it helps